# Unity3D. C#. Can can i add max and min values to zoom in this code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the 3D project I have script and i can rotate/move in the scene without doubts, but i have problem with Zoom, i can do this too close and soo far. I zoom it right to the floor or to far away to sky and i stack then. I use perspective camera.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

class ScrollAndPinch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera Camera;
    public bool Rotate;
    protected Plane Plane;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Camera == null)
            Camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        //Update Plane
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
            Plane.SetNormalAndPosition(transform.up, transform.position);

        var Delta1 = Vector3.zero;
        var Delta2 = Vector3.zero;

        //Scroll
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            Delta1 = PlanePositionDelta(Input.GetTouch(0));
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                Camera.transform.Translate(Delta1, Space.World);
        }

        //Pinch
        if (Input.touchCount >= 2)
        {
            var pos1 = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            var pos2 = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(1).position);
            var pos1b = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(0).position - Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition);
            var pos2b = PlanePosition(Input.GetTouch(1).position - Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition);

            //calc zoom
            var zoom = Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2) /
                       Vector3.Distance(pos1b, pos2b);

            //edge case
            if (zoom == 9 || zoom > 10)
                return;


            //Move cam amount the mid ray
            Camera.transform.position = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(pos1, Camera.transform.position, 1 / zoom);

            if (Rotate && pos2b != pos2)
                Camera.transform.RotateAround(pos1, Plane.normal, Vector3.SignedAngle(pos2 - pos1, pos2b - pos1b, Plane.normal));
        }

    }


    protected Vector3 PlanePositionDelta(Touch touch)
    {
        //not moved
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Moved)
            return Vector3.zero;

        //delta
        var rayBefore = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position - touch.deltaPosition);
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayBefore, out var enterBefore) && Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayBefore.GetPoint(enterBefore) - rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        //not on plane
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    protected Vector3 PlanePosition(Vector2 screenPos)
    {
        //position
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(screenPos);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.up);
    }
}
```

Sorry for noob question, i've recently started to my journey in unity3D.
How can i set the limits here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to limit the zoom within a single pinch operation you could probably do e.g.

```c#
// Configure these in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private float minZoom = 0.1f;
[SerializeField] private float maxZoom = 10f;

...
    var zoom = Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2) / Vector3.Distance(pos1b, pos2b);
    zoom = Mathf.Clamp(minZoom, maxZoom);
...
```

---

If you ment you rather want to limit the **overall** combined zoom you'll have to store and combine the zoom amounts like e.g.

```c#
private float finalZoom = 1;

...
    var zoom = Vector3.Distance(pos1, pos2) / Vector3.Distance(pos1b, pos2b);
    finalZoom *= zoom;
    finalZoom = Mathf.Clamp(minZoom, maxZoom);

    // And from here use finalZoom instead of zoom    
    Camera.transform.position = Vector3.LerpUnclamped(pos1, Camera.transform.position, 1 / finalZoom);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

```
Mathf.Clamp(xValue, xMin, xMax);
```